# How to correctly send a Google Analytics API result from server to client?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get some data from the Google Analytics API and so far my function is working quite well except for the fact that I can't manage to send the result back to the client [ 'res.send()' ]

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
const key = require('./auth.json')
const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, 
scopes)
const view_id = '######'

exports = module.exports = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {

  jwt.authorize(req, res, (err, result) => {
    google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get(
      {
        auth: jwt,
        ids: 'ga:' + view_id,
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'today',
        metrics: 'ga:pageviews'
      },
      (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
        res.send(result)
      }
    )
  })

})
```

Right now the correct result gets logged on the server side but I can't send it back to client. Expected would be that 'res.send()' returns the data to the client to be used in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up [HTTP triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and [callable triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

What you've defined is a callable trigger using `functions.https.onCall`, but you're assuming incorrectly that it receive a request and result argument.  The documentation for callables says that you get a data and a context object instead.  You are also supposed to return a promise that resolves with the data you want to send.

It it looks like you meant to write an HTTP trigger, using `functions.https.onRequest`.  That receives a request and response object, and you use the response object to send data back to the client.

Comment: Yeah, I actually mixed up the function types here. Thanks a lot, that fixed my issue :) 

& I found a nice documentation for the GA Reporting API [here](https://www.multiminds.eu/blog/2018/11/22/google-analytics-reporting-api/)